# Sequence Item has null sequencer

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am writing a test which triggers the sequence on a valid sequencer but still facing issue as "Sequence Item has null sequencer".

```
    class gen_seq_item extends uvm_seqeuence_item;
          rand bit [WIDTH-1:0] generic_signal;

          `uvm_object_utils_begin(generic_seq_item)
                 `uvm_field_int(generic_signal, UVM_ALL_ON)
          `uvm_object_utils_end

          function new(string name="generic_seq_item");
                 super.new(name);
           endfunction : new
    
           function void do_copy(uvm_object rhs);
                 generic_seq_item rhs_;
                 if($cast(rhs_,rhs)) begin
                     this.generic_signal = rhs_.generic_signal;
                 end
                 else
                     `uvm_fatal(get_full_name(), "RHS is not compatible with 
                 generic_seq_item")
           endfunction : do_copy
    
           function generic_seq_item clone();
                      clone = generic_seq_item::type_id::create("clone_generic_seq_item");
                      clone.copy(this);
                      return clone;
            endfunction : clone

    endclass

class generic_seq extends uvm_sequence#(generic_seq_item);
    `uvm_object_param_utils(generic_seq)

    rand generic_seq_item item;

    function new(string name="generic_seq");
        super.new(name);
        item = generic_seq_item::type_id::create("generic_seq_item");
    endfunction : new

    task body();
        `uvm_send(item.clone());
    endtask : body

endclass : generic_seq

    typedef uvm_sequencer#(gen_seq_item) gen_sequencer;

    class gen_agent extends uvm_agent;
             ......
             ......
        gen_driver driver_h;
        gen_sequencer seqr_h;
             ......
             ......
       function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
             ......
             seqr_h = gen_sequencer::type_id::create("gen_sequencer", this);
       endfunction
    endclass

    class gen_test extends uvm_test;
            ......
            gen_seq seq_h;
            ......
            seq_h.start(<path to agent>.seqr_h);
    endclass
```

Comment: It's not the sequence that has the problem, but the sequence_item. (_start_item_) You did not show that code

Comment: Hi Dave, 
I added the sequence_item and the sequence code in the description. Can you help take a look ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

> `uvm_send(item);

instead of

> `uvm_send(item.clone());

I have some doubt on your clone function in sequence_item class. By default, the uvm_object_utils macro creates uvm_object with factory function `clone()`. It seems to me that no point if you want to implement the clone function here.